# Проверка существования action, Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Как в коде проверить, существует ли actionActive у main контроллера?

Comment: Уточните, чем именно не устроил method_exists()?

Comment: Именно не устроило мое не глубокое познание языка php )) Thks

Comment: Имейте в виду, что относительно yii2 - это решение для частных случаев. Экшн может быть не только методом, но и классом. Если не планируете такой "глубокой" проверки, то решение подходит в большинстве случаев :)

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать получить нужный вам экшен:

```
$controller = Yii::$app->createControllerByID('site');
$action = $controller->createAction('index');
```

В случае если `$action` не `null`, значит экшен существует.